# Java HTTP Request : get content size

Tags: java, http-headers, content-length

I want to know if it's possible to get the size of a web page with a http request.

I use this to have oracle page length :

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
List<String> get = yc.getHeaderFields().get("content-Length");
```

But when I use this to a google page I do not have content-length in the header.

Comment: You must use the correct upper or lower cases. The field name is  "Content-Length" not "content-Length". You can also use the `getContentLength()` method of the `URLConnection` object. This field should be used by any application that need to send a HTTP body, and google does it so.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the correct upper or lower cases. The field name is `Content-Length` not `content-Length`. You can also use the `getContentLength()` method of the `URLConnection object`. This field should be used by any application that need to send a HTTP body, and google does it so.

Be aware that Google uses secured connections.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length is only going to be applicable if the response is not [chunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).
Generally static content will not be chunked, but in many cases dynamic content will not be chunked.

In the case of www.oracle.com, you will be redirected to www.oracle.com/index.html, which is static content and does provide Content-Length.